# how to check the current browser version

Tags: browser

How can I know the browser used from the string below.

Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; MS-RTC LM 8)

Thanks in advance for those who consider this question.

Regards
gohar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Internet Explorer 8 (`MSIE 8.0`) running on XP (`Windows NT 5.1`). [IE blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/01/09/the-internet-explorer-8-user-agent-string-updated-edition.aspx) about IE8 user agent